# Constant issue with build.gradle

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, vscode-extensions

people!

I am learning flutter right now, and have no prior experience in coding.
Recently started to connect apps with firebase, and constantly receiving errors during this stage, which are somehow related with gradle.
I found solutions for each case, but I am wondering, why I keep getting them.
I have checked the following:

1. Flutter is the latest stable version
2. VS Code is the latest stable version
3. Android Studio, X-code are the latest stable versions
4. Gradle is the latest stable version
5. Java (JDK) is the latest stable version

Now I am interested, is there a way that gradle will create latest (plugin) syntax version files instead of buildscript version automatically?  I am speaking about VS Code. As I understand, Android Studio has this capabilities. Because it is very inconvenient for a beginner to find issues case by case on the internet, which are more or less the same...
The best result would be having build.gradle.kts instead of build.gradle.
Or I am wrong and it would not solve any gradle-related issues?
It would be much appreciated if anyone could guide me with this point.

Thanks!

I have searched and was able to find solutions for each case, but I am thinking that this is the worst possible solution)))) It would be much better to set up the environment so that the issues would not arise again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.